# Angular 2 - base class incorporates child class template

Tags: angular, templates, inheritance

I try to have a popup window (with a border, a title and a close button) defined for the base class and the inside of the window shoul be defined in the child class and template

I read many inheritance tutorials, but everytime the child class overwrites the base class template instead of beeing injected inside of it

Should I use inheritance ? aggregation ? directives ? in that case, can I pass a component Class as a parameter of the directive ?

base class:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-popup-window',
    templateUrl: './popupWindow.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./popupWindow.component.css'],
})

export class PopupWindow implements OnInit {

    constructor(
    ) { }

    ngOnInit() {

    }

}
```

base template :

```
<div class="popupWindowMainDiv">
    <!-- here should be injected child class stuffs -->
</div>
```

child class :

```
import { PopupWindow } from '../popupWindow/popupWindow.component';

export class ProductSelectorComponent extends PopupWindow implements OnInit {
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you extend class in typescript/angular, only internal structure and meta is inherited. Class annotations (`@Component`) could not be inherited. So when you extend directive, you must completely override all parameters of `@Component` annotation.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-another-popup-window',
    templateUrl: './popupWindow.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./popupWindow.component.css'],
})
export class ProductSelectorComponent extends PopupWindow implements OnInit {}
```

In your particular case, you should have something like:

```
//popupWindow.component.html
<div class="header"><ng-content select="[header]"></ng-contents></div>
<div class="body"><ng-content select="[body]"></ng-contents></div>
<div class="footer"><ng-content select="[footer]"></ng-contents></div>

@Component({
    selector: 'my-another-popup-window',
    templateUrl: `
        <my-popup-window>
            <div header><h1>My Header</h1></div>
            <div body><!-- some content --></div>
        </my-popup-window>
    `,
    styleUrls: ['./popupWindow.component.css'],
})
export class ProductSelectorComponent{}
```

Comment: it works !, thanks for the time spent making a plunkr ;-)